# Confusion with lacaml type signature

Tags: types, ocaml, signature

I'm currently looking at this document and trying to identify the type signature of pp_fvec. Basically, I am trying to print a vector but it is constantly telling me I do not have the right types.

http://mmottl.github.io/lacaml/api/Lacaml_io.html

The type signature I'm interested in using is:

```
val pp_fvec : (float, 'elt) pp_vec
```

Which does something, and then calls pp_vec which has the signature:

```
type ('el, 'elt) pp_vec = Format.formatter ->
   ('el, 'elt, Bigarray.fortran_layout) Bigarray.Array1.t -> unit
```

What is going on here? What does

```
(float, 'elt) pp_vec
```

actually mean? A follow up question, how do I use this? What is the best way to look up and understand OCaml documentation? Tutorials, comments, and explanations seem really sparse at best for most libraries. I hate to keep asking these questions, but the documentation on a lot of this is really bad.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `%a` specifier in a format strings, that allows you to print value of *any* type. In general, any specifier in a printf-family format string require you to add zero or more arguments of particular type after this string, e.g.,

```
 printf "%d"
```

requires one argument of type `int`.

The `%a` specifier asks for two arguments, the first argument is the so named printer, and the second argument is the printed value itself. The printer is a function of type `'output_channel_type -> 'a -> unit` and the value must have a type of `'a`, i.e., they must match. For example, if you have a `float` vector with fortran layout of type `('el, 'elt, Bigarray.fortran_layout) Bigarray.Array1.t` named `vec`, you can use `pp_fvec` function to output it, e.g.,

```
 Format.printf "vec = %a" pp_fvec vec
```

Let me also clarify the meaning of `'output_channel_type`, I've left this to be a type variable, but usually it is concrete and is equal to the type of the channel to which particular function can write. For example, `%a` specifier in `Printf.printf` function requires you to provide a function that prints to `out_channel`, the same specifier for `Format.printf` asks for a function that prints into the output channel of type `Format.formatter`, etc. In general this type must be equal to the second type parameter of the `format` type of the formatting string.

So, to summarize, this `pp*` family of functions are used generally as a printers for the `%a` format specifier for the [Format](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) family of functions. This type of printers is also used to print into toplevel or ocaml debugger (and can be installed with `install_printer` directives).
Of course, it can be used in a standalone mode, without a `printf` function, like this:

```
 open Format
 pp_fvec std_formatter vec
```

That is roughly equivalent to the example above.

In the answer to the followup question, all OCaml libraries have a killing feature of being already self-documented with `mli` files. The best way to introduce yourself to some library is to use your favorite editor and read `mli` files of this library. With the development of modern tools like `ocamlmerlin` and `ocp-index` this is much more easier. You can just jump to the definition. You can find where particular library installs its `mli` files by `opam config var library_name:lib` command, where `library_name` is the name of the library.

Comment: Wow thank you for going into such detail. I really appreciate it.